# Autolayout animate x/y position of UIView without changing width/height

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to get used to animation with Autolayout and constraints instead of animation with frames. In my project I have a `UIView` near the top of the screen that I'm trying to animate straight downward (y position). I understand that I must modify the constraint constant value, but doing so decreases the height of my view instead of "pushing" it downward like I'm wanting. Here's my code:

```
self.topConstraint.constant = 180;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.theView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

`topConstraint` is a vertical space constraint between the top of the ViewController's view and `theView`.

Other constraints on `theView` include:

- Center X Alignment
- Horizontal Space
- Vertical Space (`self.topConstraint`)
- Vertical Space (represents the space between `theView` and the bottom of the ViewController's view)
- Pinned width
- Pinned height

How do I modify the constraint values to simply change the position of `theView` without affecting its width/height?

Comment: What other constraints are on the view? Something pinning the bottom of the view to something else? A >= hight constraint?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention I tried pinning the width and height of the view, as well. I'll update the question explaining the other constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the constraint:

> Vertical Space (represents the space between theView and the bottom of the ViewController's view)

because you don't want the height to change (you have it pinned) and you are specifying the x (centre constraint) and y (other vert constraint) positions with other constraints so it isn't required.

Your `Horizontal Space` constraint may also not be required (because you have a `Center X Alignment` constraint) - the horizontal space could be required, but more likely on the view that this one is centred on.

Comment: That did the trick! I guess I need to better understand what constraints are required. Thanks.